# IE11 readyState always 'loading', DOMContentLoaded never firing due to non SSL Content

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, document-ready, domready, onreadystatechange

On IE11 when you get the user prompt

`Only secure content is displayed.       #Show all content#`

the readyState is never changing, it is always on `loading` and the events do not fire either. Once the user clicks `Show all content` it works fine.

Unfortunately I have a site where I can't resolve the non SSL scripts and images (third party sites and user content) and it is fine if it isn't loaded, but I need the DOMContentReady event for important and securely loaded JS. Are you aware of any workaround?

Comment: The *best* workaround is to fully implement SSL, and also ensure that all third-party sites you interact with do so as well.

Comment: @ObsidianAge unfortunately this is not possible because I do not own the affected site furthermore even embedded images from users cause this issue.

Answer (score -1):

You can use protocol-less uri's in your web pages. eg. //cdn.com instead of http://cdn.com .

to list blocked content and security errors in the dev tool console first go Tools>Internet Options>Advanced tab, check "Always record developer console messages". Save changes. Navigate to your web site.
1. File>Properties menu will tell you which IE security zone the host maps to (expected internet/intranet or mixed if there are both http and https)... also the protocol its using: http(s).
2. F12>Console tab, security warnings and errors are now listed.

Comment: That's not the issue. These are third party sites with mixed content which I do not control.